# Getting this error in flutter after import flutter_pdfview package

Tags: flutter

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.1.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/barteksc/android-pdf-viewer/3.2.0-beta.1/android-pdf-viewer-3.2.0-beta.1.pom
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/barteksc/android-pdf-viewer/3.2.0-beta.1/android-pdf-viewer-3.2.0-beta.1.pom
> - https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/com/github/barteksc/android-pdf-viewer/3.2.0-beta.1/android-pdf-viewer-3.2.0-beta.1.pom
> Required by:
> project :app > project :flutter_pdfview

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 26s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Run `flutter packages get` ?

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem until I added jcenter() in my project-level build.gradle file, you do the same, and voila!! it will work

Comment: HI, Toyyibat Abdulkareem. Thank you for your answer. Just a little remark: It may - or may not - help the requester. But you could leave it to them and wait whether your answer will be accepted as the solution. No need for predicting that yours will be the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here, it seems like they changed some files in the API but they didn't solve it in the package.
I tried to visit the next URL for example, and I've reached the following path
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/barteksc
where I noticed that the files have changed.